# reference to function '&' requires l-value

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have following proble:
I have to use a predefine function, which needs a reference to function where it gets called.

Let's say I have function with a parameter:

```
void MyClass::UnitFunction(Unit* unit)
{

     predefinedFunction(.... , &MyClass::UnitFunction(unit), ...... );
}
```

When I compile this i get following error:  `'&' requires l-value`

I have actually no idea how to solve this.

Comment: `UnitFunction` returns void??

Comment: `&T::f(x)` is not a reference to a function. It is a reference to the thing it returns when called, which is probably an rvalue. Maybe you need `&T::f`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: well the code actually worked without parameter: since i added Unit* unit and use, &MyClass::UnitFunction(unit) instead of MyClass::UnitFunction it doesn't work anymore

Comment: `MyClass::UnitFunction(unit)` _calls_ the function `UnitFunction` and `&MyClass::UnitFunction(unit)` takes the address of the value returned by the call to `UnitFunction`. To take the address of the member function use `&MyClass::UnitFunction`.

Comment: &MyClass::UnitFunction, somehow doesn't work with parameters, hmm
maybe I'm not allowed to use functions with parameters for this predefined function

Comment: The concept of "pointer to a function being called using these arguments" is provided by `std::bind` (or `bind1st`).  But that requires the function you call to accept function-like arguments, not just plain pointer-to-function / pointer-to-member-function.

Comment: What is the exact declaration (signature) of `predefinedFunction` ?

Comment: I can just give you the error: Class::predefinedFunction(FTimerHandle &,float,bool,float)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'void (__cdecl MyClass::* )(Unit *)' to 'void (__cdecl MyClass::* )(void)'
I think it can only take functions without parameters

Answer (score 0):

This is the case in which functors may come in handy. I'd advice you to read something about them and when you get a grasp of them you might rethink all of your current code design and it might turn out that functors are just what you look for. Basically, a functor is a class with operator() overloaded. You can treat such an object as a function then, but it can also have its own state and other additional data saved inside (since it's still a class object).

```
class myFunctor
{
   int state;
   //other additional data you might need
   myFunctor(int _state)
   {
      state = _state;
   }
   int operator()(int a, int b)
   {
      if(state == 0)
         return a + b;
      else if(state == 1)
         //do sth else
      ...
   }
};
```

Then you can use such a functor like a casual object:

```
myFunctor obj(0); //initialization
int a = 1, b = 2;
obj(1, 2); // calling a functor
&obj; // address of the functor, which could be used to call a function somewhere else in the code
```

edit:

In your case, you could return "this" in your functor's overloaded operator() and then you could pass parameters to the functor and still pass the functor's address to the other function